# Do we really need MVC user controls, when moving from asp.net to MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are migrating and asp.NET application to MVC3.
We have a set of base operations each consisting several child functionalities.

Project has been structured as follows-

1. A master page containing Layout of the whole site.
2. Each base operation has a ASP.NET page named `BasePage1.aspx`
3. Child operations has been created in user controls like,
   `ucChildOperations.asx`.
4. Operations follow sequential order. So, on base pages we use to swap userControls `visibility`.
5. Once BasePage1.aspx operations are done  user is redirected to
   `BasePage2.aspx` and so on..

During migration to MVC, We don't see any need of `BaseView`. Thus -

1. Created Shared Layout Page.
2. Created controllers, as `Base1Controller`.
3. Created separate `Models` for each child operations. (Avoided grouping them into `BaseModles` for `loose coupling`)

While creating view we're planning to create views for each operation, `ChildOperation1View ...`

Is there any benefit in creating base views, `Base1View` and then put `MVC userControls` for child operation ?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**
Add New Item template in VS2010, has an item listed `MVC3 View User Control(ASPX).`

Comment: There's no such thing as "MVC user controls".  What are you referring to?  Html helpers?  Your description is also confusing, it would help if you could explain more clearly.

Comment: Actually there are MVC Usercontrols, they do belong to MVC 2. I hope he's not planning to use MVC 2 though